# Swift timer label recurring 9

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have created a simple timer in swift 3.

For some reason though, even though it works the label display too many numbers :S it displays a crazy amount of 9's. Is this to do with rounding?

Thanks, code below :)

---

```
var swiftTimer : Timer?
var swiftCounter: Double = 0.00

@IBOutlet weak var displayTimeLBL: UILabel!

@IBAction func start(_ sender: Any) {
    swiftTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

@IBAction func stop(_ sender: Any) {
    if swiftTimer != nil{
        swiftTimer?.invalidate()
        swiftCounter = 0.00
        updateLabel()
        swiftTimer = nil
    }
}

func updateLabel(){
    displayTimeLBL.text = String(swiftCounter)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func updateCounter(){
    swiftCounter+=0.01
    round(swiftCounter)
    updateLabel()
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UmVk.jpg)

Comment: Why do you need your timer to repeat 100 times per second? You don't need to display every single fraction of a second to the user

Comment: Don't use a timer to measure time. Just store the start date and get the timeInterval from now

Comment: What made you want to round? Are you wanting the timer going up by seconds? Milliseconds?

Comment: You don't need to check if `swiftTimer` is `nil`; the conditional  unwrap in `swiftTimer?.invalidate` will do this for you.  Instead of using a double, use an NSDecimalNumber or an integer that you divide by 100, or use String.format to trim the trailing decimal places, but as Leo said, don't use a counter; use time intervals from a start date; `Timer` is not accurate and you will get significant drift using a counter. Using a time interval will let you use a more reasonable update frequency, such as 0.1 second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest Solution:

```
func updateCounter(){
        swiftCounter+=0.01
        round(swiftCounter)
        swiftCounter = Double(round(100*swiftCounter)/100)
        updateLabel()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want two fractions then you can use `swiftCounter.round(2)` instead of `round(swiftCounter)`

to update the text use:

```
displayTimeLBL.text = "\(swiftCounter.round(2))"
```

Here is the `Double` extension used:

```
extension Double {
   func round(_ places: Int) -> Double {
      let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
      return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
   }
}
```